# Fragment recalling onResume

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am adding Fragment in A activity and went to B activity from A-Fragment(not finishing A activity). when i finish the B Activity, A-Fragment is recalled, any one suggest/explain me why it is happen

Here is my code:

```
FragmentManager frgmanager = getFragmentManager();
frgmanager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
FragmentTransaction frgTransaction = frgmanager.beginTransaction();
            frgTransaction.replace(R.id.inflate_layout, MessagesList.newInstance());
frgTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
frgTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Refer Handling the Fragment Lifecycle  of https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

It is by-design behavior.

Fragments inside of A Activity are resumed when you go back to A Activity. Refer to [the activity-fragment lifecycle dancing diagram](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle), you can see *"User returns to the Activity"* at `onResume()`.

When Garbage Collection is occurred, it also hits `onResume` as the fragment will start from `onCreateView`.